# WPF DataGrid and the WPF Toolkit on Codeplex

Tags: wpf, user-interface, datagrid, wpftoolkit

ok, I'm totally confused. I'm new to WPF (don't know how many times I read this sentence in the last week) and I'm investigating in DataGrids for my project.

The DataGrid in WPF 4.0 does not provide too many features. **Can anybody tell me if that grid is the same as in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)?**

Did the code from that project became part of .NET4.0?

**If not, is there anywhere documentation on the WPF Toolkit DataGrid?**

thank you

Comment: You could also give the Extended WPF Toolkit a try: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm on it. But the ext. toolkit from Xceed has this community vs. commercial version where-is-the-difference-issue. I'm also trying Telerik, DevExpress, Syncfusion and ComponentOne. And I'm really getting sick already ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `DataGrid` started as external control in WPF Toolkit but then was included in standard control library in WPF 4 (see [related topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613588%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#new_controls)). So if you`re using WPF 4 then you don`t need no external toolkits to use `DataGrid`, and all it`s documentation can be found on [MSDN: DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

There is a [topic about datagrids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112518/what-wpf-datagrid-controls-are-worth-the-money-and-or-effort) here. It`s old but still more or less actual.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted to know.